# How to connect to SQL server with java -D from cmd

Tags: java, sql, cmd

I want to run a java program that will connect to a SQL server.
The credentials to that server I would like to get from cmd by using the -D flag.

Could someone write how do I exactly do it and how do I retrieve those properties (System.getProperty()??? and what is the parameter I need to write in).

Comment: I realize that I need to use "integratedSecurity=true" somehow in the cmd, what I do not understand is how to extract or how to create a 'Connection' in my java program by executing the way I described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To learn more about JDBC connections, here you find a quite good tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-create-database.htm

Re -D, taking the example from the link above, you simply replace

```
static final String USER = "username";
static final String PASS = "password";
```

with

```
static final String USER = System.getProperty("username");
static final String PASS = System.getProperty("password");
```

Then you can pass the credentials as in

```
java -jar -Dusername=<username> -Dpassword=<password> the.jar
```

Another note: Passing credentials via command line is insecure, because they are also fully visible in the process list.